# Saving things to the executable of the applications (so it will be there on next application launch) in C#

Tags: c#, settings

Alright, so I know about the Settings.Properties.Default.* Stuff, but thats not what im trying to use.. I'm trying to develop my own class, ill show you:

```
public sealed class SettingsHolder<T>
{
   public SettingsHolder(){}
   public T Setting
   {
      get{ /*return setting*/ }
      set( /*store setting*/  }
   }
}
```

so then i could compile that to a dll, and reference it in an application, and do something like this

```
SettingsHolder<string> stringHolder = new SettingsHolder<string>();
stringHolder.Setting = "hello world";
```

and on next application launch

```
string welcome = stringHolder.Setting;
```

and welcome should = "hello world".. is this at all possible? i had origannally tried to disect the *actual* properties.settings class, but with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET/VS settings framework already does *exactly* what you indicate that you're trying to do, without the clumsy runtime casts and generic classes.  Absent a very compelling reason *not* to use it, that is what you should use.  It already handles persisted user-level settings.

If for some reason you absolutely cannot use that, either store the settings directly in a file somewhere in the user's AppData, or use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx).  You will have to write your own persistence model for it.

If an application could rewrite its own executable code *on disk*, it would raise all sorts of thorny questions about security and reliability.  Besides, security restrictions on Vista and Windows 7 would prevent it from functioning correctly anyway - unless it's a ClickOnce app, it's probably installed in a program folder (i.e. Program Files), and you'd need a user with administrative privileges to elevate the process in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. The setting data has to be stored somewhere, in some file or database (when you compile your app you have .exe.config file).

Comment: would it be possible for my class to generate a dll or other to store all the settings being used in that app?

Answer (score -1):

Whe you do `new classname()` you create the object with *members* of that class initialised in memory to their default values. e.g. if your `SettingsHolder` class contained an `int _n;` it would be initialised to 0.  Alternatively, you can of course initialise your member variable to a specific value, e.g. `int _n = 5;`

As far as I recall, this is in the definition of the language, which therefore precludes what you suggest; which is essentially something along the lines of 'self-modifying code with state'.

Therefore, you *do* need to use mechanisms to store state in your programs - such as Properties.Settings (which saves to XML config files by default), or a DB for example.

You don't really need to dissect the Properties.Settings class. If you access Settings from the project properties menu, and add a 'User' or 'Application' setting. It can then be accessed with `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName`. You do need to instruct the code to save changes to the properties, if I recall correctly.

Comment: It would be appreciated if down-votes would be explained with a comment!